# Mount Docker container's root filesystem as read only

Tags: docker

I want to mount a container's root filesystem as read-only when I run the following command:

```sh
docker ps --quiet --all | \
  xargs docker inspect \
    --format '{{ .Id }}: ReadonlyRootfs={{ .HostConfig.ReadonlyRootfs }}'
```

If the above command returns `true`, it means the root filesystem is mounted read-only. If the above command returns `false`, it means the root filesystem is writable.

When I run the command, `ReadonlyRootfs=false` is being shown.  How do I make it show `true`?

Answer (score 5):

The root file-system gets mounted read-only when you pass the flag `--read-only` to the `docker run` command, e.g.:

```
$ docker run -it --read-only centos
[root@87e0f56dc341 /]# touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Read-only file system
```

Help pages:

```
$ docker run --help | grep read-only
      --read-only
        Mount the container's root filesystem as read only
```