# How do I make a containers root filesystem r/o but allow writing to WORKDIR

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to make the root filesystem as read-only as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868801/dockers-mount-containers-root-filesystem-as-read-only):

```
docker run --read-only ... myapp
```

But, I also need to allow the application running in the container access to its folder `/app`.  The application needs some temporary storage, but I need to limit its access to everything for security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you mount into the container with a `docker run -v` option isn't "part of the root filesystem" and can have its own access mode.  If you just need some scratch space within the container, you can use the [`docker run --tmpfs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#mount-tmpfs---tmpfs) option to mount an empty in-memory filesystem somewhere.

```
$ docker run --rm --read-only busybox \
> sh -c 'touch /tmp/foo && ls /tmp'
touch: /tmp/foo: Read-only file system

$ docker run --rm --read-only --tmpfs /tmp busybox \
> sh -c 'touch /tmp/foo && ls /tmp'
foo
```

You can do the same thing with named volumes:

```
$ docker volume create vol
vol
$ docker run --rm --read-only -v vol:/tmp busybox touch /tmp/foo
$ docker run --rm --read-only -v vol:/tmp busybox ls /tmp
foo
```

You *don't* want to do this with the directory containing your application's source code.  For security reasons, if you're concerned enough to make the root filesystem read-only, you don't want to risk the application's code being overwritten.  If your application code does wind up in a volume, Docker will treat it as valuable user data and refuse to ever update it.  So pick some directory other than `/app` for this (a subdirectory `/app/data` would work fine just so long as it's okay to start empty).